# Multiple User Account bit-torrent client

Tags: bittorrent, switch-user, multiple-users

So I recently setup Ubuntu 12.04, and currently looking for a bit-torrent client where I can create multiple user accounts.

The plan is to have more than 1 user accounts, and each user can monitor their activity via web-interface.

So far after did a bit of research I found:

- Deluge (which offers multiple **user-interface**)
- rtorrent (which I would love to use this due to its light-weightedness).

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: You've found two - what's wrong with those? Why aren't they perfect *for you*?

Comment: Those two does not (afaik) have the feature i want, where different user can (sort of) login by providing their credentials and monitor their activity.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenSeedbox](http://www.openseedbox.com/) seems to match your requirements, but more like a server rather than a client.